# Locating 5 row of grid at the center (with picture)

Tags: html, css, sass, next.js

I am using Next.js and SCSS and trying to locate 5 & 3 rows of images at the center of the page with responsive grid system.

I just need to slightly adjust images location to the right side but contents do not move at all.

[image]

here is the code :

**Next.js**

```
// So basically ui.container wraps up li.item which are images.

<ul className="container">
          {stores.map(store => (
            <li onClick={this.open} key={store.id} className="item">
              <img
                src={store.thumb}
                onClick={() => this.storeDetail(store.id)}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
section {
  background: pink;
}

.store-list-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 200px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **justify-content:center** for aligining center

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 50px);
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but the contents overlap each other. I found solution at here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS9QgrG2oXo

Comment: @GoonGamja Good

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found on youtube is using `mixin` function in SCSS.

It needs calculation so I am still looking at it to understand how it works.

I would be appreciated if someone explains how it works

**item element and mixin**

```
@mixin grid($cols, $mgn) {
  float: left;
  margin-right: $mgn;
  margin-bottom: $mgn;
  width: ((100% - (($cols - 1) * $mgn)) / $cols);
  &:nth-child(#{$cols}n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.item {
    @include grid(5, 2%);
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

**li tags**

```
 {stores.map(store => (
            <li onClick={this.open} key={store.id} className="item">
              <img
                src={store.thumb}
                onClick={() => this.storeDetail(store.id)}
                alt={`${store.name} image`}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
```